# How to get an specific element in JSON?

Tags: android, json

If I have a JSON like below:

```
{
  "Division": [
      {
        "DivisionId": 1,
        "DivisionName" : "A"
      },
      {
        "DivisionId": 2,
        "DivisionName" : "B"
      }
  ],
 "Title": [
     {
       "TitleId": 11,
       "Title": "Title 1"
     },
     {
       "TitleId": 12,
       "Title": "Title 2"
     }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the `Division` only with its values inside? What I'm trying to achieve is to put the values of `Division` inside my `ArrayList`. I'm using Volley to get the JSON result and what I tried is on the `onResponse` I used `JSONArray divisionArr = response.getJSONArray("Division");` and loop it here's my code

```
 JSONArray divisionArr = response.getJSONArray("Division");

                for (int i = 0; i < divisionArr.length(); i++) {
                    Division division = new Division();
                    JSONObject divisionObj = (JSONObject) divisionArr.get(i);

                    division.setId(divisionObj.getInt("DivisionId"));
                    division.setName(divisionObj.getString("DivisionName"));

                    divisionArrayList.add(division);
                }
```

But I'm having an error `ParseError`, I maybe doing it wrong, but I don't know what is it. Please help, thank you.

///////
Here's my `Volley request`

```
public void getData(Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    try{

        String syncCall = Constants.VOLLEY;

        request = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                syncCall,
                null,
                listener,
                errorListener);

        request.setRetryPolicy(
                new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        60000,//DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, // 2500
                        1,//DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, // 1
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)); //1f

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then in my Activity

```
  private void callSyncVolley() {

    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("Fetching data....");
    pd.show();

    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray divisionArr = response.getJSONArray("Division");

                for (int i = 0; i < divisionArr.length(); i++) {
                    Division division = new Division();
                    JSONObject divisionObj = (JSONObject) divisionArr.get(i);

                    division.setId(divisionObj.getInt("DivisionId"));
                    division.setName(divisionObj.getString("DivisionName"));

                    divisionArrayList.add(division);
                }

                pd.dismiss();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: Timeout/NoConnection");
                pd.dismiss();
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                //TODO
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: AuthFailureError");
                pd.dismiss();
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                //TODO
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: ServerError");
                pd.dismiss();
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                //TODO
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: NetworkError");
                pd.dismiss();
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                //TODO
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: ParseError");
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

    VolleyRequestManager.getInstance().doRequest().getData(listener, errorListener);
}
```

The error only shows `Error Response code: ParseError`

Comment: Please post the full error

Comment: Provide the error report and code you are using to parse this json

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Can you post the full trace message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it right, I recode the whole thing, checked my json result and here's my code

```
Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray divisionArr = response.getJSONArray("Division");

                if(!divisionArr.equals(null)){
                    for(int i = 0; i < divisionArr.length(); i++){
                        Division division = new Division();
                        JSONObject divisionObj = (JSONObject) divisionArr.get(i);

                        division.setId(divisionObj.getInt("DivisionId"));
                        division.setName(divisionObj.getString("DivisionName"));

                        divisionList.add(division);
                    }
                }

                pd.dismiss();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pd.dismiss();
            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, If you try to get using `opt` it will get value or null, so you can check that produced further

[get and opt type](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

> - Use getType() to retrieve a mandatory value. This fails with a JSONException if the requested name has no value or if the value
>     cannot be coerced to the requested type.
> - Use optType() to retrieve an optional value. This returns a system- or user-supplied default if the requested name has no value or if the
>     value cannot be coerced to the requested type.

Example:
getJSONArray - Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray, or throws otherwise., so we can't handle the upcoming line of code it will go to try block,

But optJSONArray - Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray, or null otherwise., so using that null value we can handle the code easily

```
try {
    JSONArray divisionArr = response.optJSONArray("Division");

    if(divisionArr != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < divisionArr.length(); i++) {
            Division divisoin = new Division();
            JSONObject divisionObj =divisionArr.optJSONObject(i);

            if(divisionObj == null) {
                continue;
            }

            divisionArr.setId(divisionObj.optInt("DivisionId"));
            divisionArr.setName(divisionObj.optString("DivisionName"));

            divisionArrayList.add(applicationType);
        }
    }

    pd.dismiss();

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: what is `optJSONArray` ?

Comment: what is the use of `opt` ?

Comment: I updated my answer have a look. If any doubts please let me know.

Comment: I updated my code cause I mistype. But I tried your code and I'm still having the ParseError :(

Comment: Sorry your **"DivisionName" : A** this is not formatted correctly, It should be **"DivisionName" : "A"**, You can ask your backend team to correct this, that is the only option.

Comment: After changing "DivisionName" : "A" also you are getting error..?

Comment: Could you please add your complete error log in question.?

Comment: It only shows `D/NavigationActivity: Error Response code: ParseError`

Comment: If you add complete log it will be better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149667/discussion-between-mori-and-muthukrishnan-rajendran).

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON format is invalid,

```
{
  "Division": [
      {
        "DivisionId": 1,
        "DivisionName" : A
      },
      {
        "DivisionId": 2,
        "DivisionName" : B
      }
  ],
 "Title": [
     {
       "TitleId": 11,
       "Title": "Title 1"
     },
     {
       "TitleId": 12,
       "Title": "Title 2"
     }
  ],
}
```

I just pasted your format [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

1. `divisionArr.setName(divisionObj.getString("DivisionName"));` &&

You are trying to access a String which is not wrapped in double quotes,the String `A` and String `B` is not wrapped in double quotes.

2. Unnecessary comma at the end of the array `],`

Comment: I have mistype something on my code, but I correct it now and updated my code in the question. I will try to check my json format thank you.

Comment: @mori [Check your JSON format here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) Again you did not remove the comma.

Comment: My json now is valid. But still I'm having the error.  it always goes to `else if (error instanceof ParseError) `

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Volley use Retrofit coz it'll provide you each JSON Element seperately. And to know how to use Retrofit check this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792).